# make mysql run php file every 8 seconds

Tags: php, mysql, api

I'm using an API to get the `Qatar 2022` results; everything is working fine using php, however I would like to update results every 8 seconds on the database. I am getting API results using php code, so I would like to make mysql(mariadb) run a php file every 8 seconds

I had try to use this code but it is not working

```sql
DELIMITER @@
CREATE EVENT insert_imediato
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
DO
BEGIN
    DECLARE cmd CHAR(255);
    DECLARE result int(10);
    SET cmd=CONCAT('C:\xampp\php\windowsXamppPhp\php.exe', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\qatar\qatarjob1.php');
    SET result = sys_exec(cmd);
END @@
DELIMITER ;
```

I'm using `Windows` and `xampp`, however the idea is to put this on the server

Comment: perhaps you need `CONCAT_WS` and use a space to separate the arguments

Comment: Why try to do this through MySQL? Why not just get Windows task schedular to do it? And why so frequently? 8 seconds seems needlessly demanding, unless you think some team will score some hundreds of goals in a match.

Comment: true, 8 seconds its demanding, I have this working with a windows script, but if I put this on the server online, I believe this option isnt possible anymore.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a function and call it recursively after a sleep. Can this help you?

```
function afterDelay($delay){
    // Your query to insert data in database here.
    include ("C:\xampp\htdocs\qatar\qatarjob1.php");
    echo "after $delay Seconds \n";
    sleep($delay);
    afterDelay($delay);
}

afterDelay(8);
```

Comment: I am  a little confuse, is this php with mysql, or can I do this in mysql, also for some reason the line "cmd=concat(....)"  its not calling the php script file, should it be?

Comment: I edited my code, You are right I confused you. I just wanted to tell where you can put the query to insert data in SQL. Its PHP.

Comment: this is the best alternative so far, I will implement it for now, however I have to have the page open every time there is a game, the ideal was to have the server or the database doing this automatically

Comment: You can run it in the shell with php the command would be php -f functionFile.php

Comment: yes, it was my first alternative option, a script that makes the cmd call  "php path_to_php_file", was not using the -f, but it was working just fine, after this last answer had made and extra php file that calls the php file with javascript and fetch, the thing is that I have to have that page open every time there is a game, but for me its even better than the script on the computer

Comment: There must be a way to do this on cpanel or on mysql database

Comment: if you are using Linux you can set a crontab job to restart the script ruining in a specific  time and on windows you schedule a task. which services does you host provides for task scheduling?